# Diffusion flux Einstein relation

Tags: diffusion

I want to derive the diffusion flux $J_D$ of charged particles with charge $e$ moving in the z direction where we apply an electric field $\vec{E}=E\hat{z}$ in order to proof the Einstein relation that is often given without derivation or using Kubo's derivation. I am looking for an easy approach assuming thermal equilibrium. The mean number density at $z$ is $n(z)$. I tried the following:

$$\frac{n(z+dz)}{n(z)}=\frac{e^{-\beta W(z+dz)}}{e^{-\beta W(z)}},$$

where I used $W(z)=-eEz$ and $W(z+dz) = -eE(z+dz)$ so these are potential energies. From this I derive that

$$\frac{n(z+dz)}{n(z)} \approx  1+\beta eEdz.$$

Using the expansion $e^x \approx 1+x$ in the last part.

This then gives with $$J_D = -D\frac{dn}{dz}$$

$$J_D = -Dn(z)\beta eE,$$

which is exactly what I need to derive the Einstein relation using $J_\mu = n\mu E$ and $J_D + J_\mu = 0$ so that we find:

$$\frac{\mu}{D} = e\beta,$$

which is indeed the Einstein relation.

My question is: how can we get away with deriving this using the potential energy and not the total energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total energy is the sum of the potential and kinetic energies but, given that the temperature is independent of position $z$, the average kinetic energy is also independent of $z$. So it is only necessary to consider the variation of the potential energy with $z$.

Incidentally, this derivation can also be presented in terms of particles at dynamical equilibrium in a gravitational field (again under the assumption that the system is isothermal) or in terms of osmotic pressure. For some discussion of the different versions, see the Wikipedia page on [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion).